# How can I use laravel chunk() in the view?

Tags: laravel, view

I need to use chunk(500) to select records from an enormous table, but since the last chunk is what remains after the chunks of 500, I keep getting an error about the id missing. When I use first(), I don't get the error because there is no attempt to read the last chunk of less than 500. I have searched for many hours and cannot find an example of using chunk in the view and stopping the read of the last incomplete chunk when the last record has been reached.  Can anyone please help me?

This code works with no errors, but only reads the first 500 chunk.
@if(isset($machs))
@foreach($machs->chunk(500)->first() as $row)

I have found examples of chunk in the controller, but don't know how that would work because the view is where I am printing the data out.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give.

I did try a forelse loop and an if block with the count of the collection, but neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is not standard to get all the data and pass it to the view with blade template if your data is enormous.

what you should do is use pagination instead and show it per page.

if you need to to process the data then use chunking in the controller first and then pass what necessary to the view

Comment: I am using bootstrap tables with pagination on the view page, but with that the page takes way too long to load. When I add the chunk with first, the load is MUCH faster, but when I remove the first() I get the error due to the last incomplete chunk.

Comment: Also, I am not processing the data. I am only selecting the data to display on the index.blade page.

Comment: How many row of data in your database? Trust me you will not want to do that in the long run.

Comment: There are millions of records, so I really need some way to speed up the load process.

Comment: Then as I said, use pagination from back end instead. Or maybe I misunderstood something? Can you show me your controller that pass the data to your blade template?